# Failed to login in to Agentsolo.com using StackExchange OpenID

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

According to [the post on stackexchange blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/#comment-59100), I should report this here.

I have an account with [agentsolo.com](http://agentsolo.com) and want to add my StackExchange OpenID. I had a working OpenID associated with it (Verisign or MyOpenID, i believe). I removed it and tried to add the StackExchange OpenID, but everytime AgentSolo says `Failed to login!`